# Is it possible to store double[][] array in ArrayList<double[][]> in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, double

I have been thinking for a while about this issue. I am in need of a class that can take in some `double[][]` array and then store this array for future usage. The only storage option that I can think of is storing a `double[][]` in an `ArrayList<>()` of `double[][]`'s.

I did implement it as follows:

```
public class AddToArray {
    public String[] parameterNames;
    public ArrayList<double[][]> parametersToChange;    

public AddToArray(String[] parameterNames){
    this.parameterNames = parameterNames;
}

public void addToArray(double[][] parametersToChange) throws InsufficientInputException     

    for(int i = 0; i < parametersToChange.length; i++){
        if(parametersToChange[i].length != this.parameterNames.length)
            throw new InsufficientInputException("DATA DIMENSION MISMATCH");
    }
    // This below gives nullpointexception.
    this.parametersToChange.add(parametersToChange);

}
```

I call by this example:

```
        double[][] parametersToChange = {{0.005,0.006},{0.007,0.008}};
    String[] par = {"SI1","SI2"};
    AddToArray abc = new AddToArray(par);
    abc.addToArray(parametersToChange);
    System.out.println(abc.parametersToChange.get(0)[0][0]); // this would (in my ideal world) print out 0.005
```

I receive a null pointer exception for this call and I am thinking that its not possible to make an ´ArrayList´. What other options do I have, I really can't figure this one out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you initialize the arraylist?

```
parametersToChange = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: And it works. I feel embarrassed but it definitely solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `parametersToChange`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way generics are implemented in Java (type erasure), arrays and generics don't work well together.

Joshua Bloch has a discussion on the topic in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), you can find that section [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=java%20mixing%20generics%20and%20arrays&source=bl&ots=yYKoLfv2M2&sig=Jtg3NrxjzIvyVwlfhmFH78qiDjc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=alHPUtX3LdXesASn5IHwDA&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=java%20mixing%20generics%20and%20arrays&f=false).